# How do we know there is a closed point of $Y \cap U$ where $Y \cap U$ is a closed subset of open subscheme $U$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme. Let $Y$ be a locally closed subset of $X$ and $U$ an open subset of $X$ such that 
$U \cap Y$ is non-empty and closed in $U$. I would like to deduce there is a closed point of $Y \cap U$.

What I have done: Let $z \in U \cap Y$ and take the affine open neighborhood $z \in \operatorname{Spec}A \subset U$. Then $\operatorname{Spec}A \cap  Y$ is a closed subset of $\operatorname{Spec}A$, hence an affine scheme and it follows that there exists a closed point $z_0$ with respect to the topology of $\operatorname{Spec}A \cap  Y$ . Now I am trying to prove that $\overline{ \{ z_0 \} }^{Y \cap U} = \{z_0\}$, but I seem to be stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without further conditions: let $X=Y=U$ be a scheme with [no closed points](https://www.math.utah.edu/~schwede/Papers/SchemeWithoutPoints.pdf). The most common assumption used to guarantee existence of a closed point is quasi-compactness, see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646995/show-that-in-a-quasi-compact-scheme-every-point-has-a-closed-point-in-its-closur) for a proof.

Comment: Thank you... in the context I'm reading, $X$ is a finite type over an algebraically closed field, which I probably shouldn't have omitted in the question. But even with this additional assumption, I'm still not seeing it because it's not clear to me that $Y \cap U$ will be quasi-compact..

Comment: I agree, you should not have omitted this. To solve your question in this case, a scheme finite type over a noetherian scheme is again noetherian, and then every subscheme is quasicompact. Alternatively, you can solve this with just the Nullstellensatz, see for instance [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588901/showing-that-there-is-a-closed-point-in-the-preimage/3589466#3589466).

Comment: I see.. thank you again